# using axis x,y in qweb odoo check printing

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, qweb

I need a help in Odoo check printing direction, depending on the language direction.
so the 0,0 point change based on language direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the direction in `Settings -> Translations -> languages`.
Choose a language and change the `Direction` field according to the language use.

To modify the way numbers are printed use `Decimal Separator` and `Thousands Separator` then add the `Separator Format`.